# How to include multiple values under a section in inifile

Tags: linux, git, puppet

I am trying to create a puppet manifest using inifile. This would be for a configuration file where I need to have the following format.

```
[safe]
    directory = /home/foo
    directory = /home/test
    directory = /home/something
```

I know that there is a way to use directory1, and directory2 but I was wondering if there is a way to do it without changing the directory since it needs that specific attribute. This implementation is meant for puppet manifest.
Also, I was thinking `puppetlabs/inifile` module but if there is another option to achieve this would be great too.

Thanks for the help in advance

So far, I have an implementation like:

```
ini_setting { 'procedure cache size':
  ensure         => present,
  path           => '/var/lib/somethning/test.config',
  section        => 'safe',
  setting        => 'directory',
  value          => '/home/foo',
  indent_char    => "\t",
}
```

This is for each directory. The purpose for this implementation is to address the new git configuration for safe.repository in the recent update. My understanding is that for multiple directories, it adds a new value as `directory = <directory>` I don't believe that it likes directories separate by commas.

Comment: When you say "using inifile", do you mean you are trying to use the module `puppetlabs/inifile` to manage the file in question?

Comment: Also, does your target file support specifying the directories as a comma- or space-separated list, or does each one need to be specified by its own `directory =` entry?

Comment: Thanks for the comment John, and yes I meant puppetlabs/inifile. I just updated my initial question with more information. This implementation is meant to manage git configuration for the safe repository. Therefore, my understanding is that it requires it own `directory` entry

Comment: As far as I am aware, puppetlabs/inifile does not support multiple entries with the same section and name. But if it did, then I am confident that you would exercise that by declaring a separate `ini_setting` resource for each one, much along the lines of the one you present in the question.

Comment: Must you use `ini_file` or is any working solution ok (perhaps looping through an array with directories and/or file_line and/or using a template).

Comment: Any solution is welcome but it would have to include a puppet implementation in the solution, but maybe I should think about a template solution.

Answer (score 0):

First I thought about `file_line`, but this is not idempotent for multi-line settings (you get problems when you run again). You can try:
Sample puppet code dir.pp

```
$safe_directories="directory = /home/foo
directory = /home/test
directory = /home/something"
    
notice "Testing\n${safe_directories}"
    
file { "/tmp/result.ini":
  ensure => present,
  content => template('/tmp/layout.erb'),
}

notice "Check /tmp/result.ini"
```

Sample template /tmp/layout.erb

```
[unsafe]
  directory=/unsafe
[safe]
  <%=@safe_directories%>
  otherfield=secure
[header3]
  nothing = here
```

Now run command from commandline

```
puppet apply dir.pp
```